# Issues with ffmpeg image options

Tags: ffmpeg

I've some issues with combining multiple image options in ffmpeg.
My sample command with all options I want to change:

```
ffmpeg -y -i sample.jpg -qscale:v 2 -pix_fmt rgb24 -vf scale=640:480 eq=brightness=0.5:contrast=0.5:saturation=0.5 -f png output.png
```

I've several issues with this command and have been trying to rewrite it for a while, here is what I found:

1. after -vf I cannot specify both scale and eq, if I use only one it will work.
2. I cannot for some reason use -f png option.

For 1. I got such results (for both removed -f png option):

- If I have both scale and eq: 
   `[NULL @ 0000024581fd1a80] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'eq=brightness=0.5:contrast=0.5:saturation=0.5' eq=brightness=0.5:contrast=0.5:saturation=0.5: Invalid argument`
- If I remove scale or eq it works

Is there any way to combine scale with options such as brightness and contrast. If I want to add another effects such as: colorchannelmixer how to add it?

Why am I getting this error with -f png option, how can I specify the format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple filters in a filterchain are separated by a comma, and ideally enclosed in quotes..

`-vf "scale=640:480,eq=brightness=0.5:contrast=0.5:saturation=0.5"`

---

If the file extension is specified (and correctly) then `-f` is not needed. Otherwise, for image formats, the syntax is `-c:v png -f image2`.

Comment: Thank's for help.
I've already figured I shall use -c option instead of -v.
I've applied the option with "" in -vf and it's working now.